# Make list of ones and zeroes in R with probability

Tags: r

New to R, looking for some help with a problem.

I'm looking to make a numeric vector in R of length N where the elements are either a 1 or a 0. I'd like roughly 30% of the elements to be ones. The code I have thus far

```
probs=rep(0.3,N)
x<-sample(0:1,N,replace=TRUE,prob=probs)
```

But this returns the following error:

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
 incorrect number of probabilities
```

I'm sure I'm making a very simple mistake here. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You receive an error as the probability weights should be the same length as the vector being sampled .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
N <- 100
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(c(0,1),size=N,replace=TRUE,prob=c(.7,.3))
##
> table(x)
x
 0  1 
71 29
```

Equivalently, you can represent this with a Binomial distribution:

```
set.seed(123)
y <- rbinom(N,1,.3)
> table(y)
y
 0  1 
71 29
```

Answer (score 1):

For extremely simple cases like yours,  it's just as easy to do

```
foo<-c(rep(1,3),rep(0,7))
sample(foo,100,replace=TRUE)
```

For more complicated or varying sets of weights, do what the other answers and comments suggest.